# Unable to detect lines in a text file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check whether a given *word is in a `.txt` file* . The problem is that, It is not detecting anything...

**This is my code:**

```
with open(r'C:\\Users\\intel\\Downloads\\test.txt') as f: 
    for password in f:
        for lines in password: 

            if lines == '123456':
                print ("[+] Password Found: %s" % lines) 
                break

            else:
                print("[-]", end=' ')
```

**And this is my text file:**

```
123456
1234667654675
hello
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: don't edit your question with code that doesn't match the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Your inner for loop is unnecessary, you're beginning to loop over characters.

```
for password in f:

    if password == '123456':
```

Comment: Then also it is showing nothing (after removing the inner loop) @Sayse

Comment: chances are its including new lines then, try `if password.rstrip() == "123456"`

Comment: @AbhaySalvi - No worries, you might want to stop people from ending their password with whitespace

Comment: Yeah i am trying dictionary attack (for educational purpose) using 10 million passwords. Any advice or help to make it more better?? or a better 10 million password list??